# RPC call - getting "No service found at this URL"

Tags: rpc, snapshots, bootstrapping

How far back can an rpc call go when wanting to retrieve block information?  This call returns a block

rpc get /chains/main/blocks/4506511

this also returns a block

rpc get /chains/main/blocks/4506510

This returns "No service found at this URL"

rpc get /chains/main/blocks/4502999

Don't know if this occurs because of the bootstrap I did last night and the rolling snapshot I used (https://mainnet-v17-shots.nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com/mainnet-4506511.rolling BMMVeYPMoZvDCREcZDgkdTrUDvu8YodpSJtYxhHmGkQ1psEaSEW)

Answer (score 1):

A rolling node retains and supplies information for only a limited number of cycles. To access older blocks, you must have at least a full node or even an archive node depending which information you are querying. If only blocks then full should be sufficient.

See also here:
https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/history_modes.html